# code does not write anything in the file

Tags: python, scapy

```
from scapy.all import *

p=rdpcap("/home/jaghanata/Desktop/amostra.pcap")
##
##for i in range(len(p)):
##    p[i].display()
##  
##        

#intervalo de 10
f1 = open("/home/jaghanata/Desktop/parte1.txt", 'w')
for i in range(0,len(p)/10):

    p[i].display()
    f1.write(str(p[i]))
f1.close()
```

the code does not write anything in parte1.txt but   p[i].display() works

Comment: try to print `str(p[i])` before you write it to see if it's converted properly to a string.

Comment: Try to hard code some text in the file. Does the file have permission to write or the folder?

Comment: Thanks for your comment!